# Angularjs directive depends on outer directive

Tags: angularjs, workflow, directive

I need to develop a workflow editor in Angularjs

This requires a directive(inner) that should add a div with some data and data for this directive should come from another directive(outer)

series of divs will be added right, top or bottom based on parameters.

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't post any code or exact requirements, please take a look on this demo where it shows calling directive from other directive:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div directive-foo></div>
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.directive('directiveFoo', function() {
return {
    template: '<div directive-bar="123">bar</div>',
    replace: true,
    controller: function() {
        console.log('in foo ctrl');
        this.isFooAlive = function() {
            return 'Foo is alive and well';
        }
    }
}
});
app.directive('directiveBar', function() {
return {
    controller: function() {
        console.log('in bar ctrl');
    },
    require: 'directiveFoo',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, fooCtrl) {
        console.log(fooCtrl.isFooAlive());
    }
}
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
}
```

<kbd>[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSAfL/)</kbd>

Hope it will help you

Comment: Hi Maxim! Thanks for your reply. I am wondering how 'fooCtrl' is referring to 'directiveFoo' controller? I mean what is the convention followed?

Comment: take a look on `link: function(scope, element, attrs, fessCtrl)`, scope, element and attrs defined by default and 4th element is controller, you can call it as you want